# Windows Phone 8.1 template not appearing

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I've downloaded the Windows Phone 8.1 SDK Update and I'm attempting to make a Windows Phone 8.1 project. I've updated visual studio with the latest patches but the only template options I have for 8.1 is the standard Windows Store apps as seen in the screenshot below:

[Windows Store](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Np3Cm.png)

Any idea how I can get "Windows Phone" to appear with the appropriate OS target?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you didn't install everything. Because i've got actually another [screenshot](http://oi60.tinypic.com/120lef9.jpg). Following [this link](http://dev.windows.com/en-us/develop/download-phone-sdk) you must install Visual Studio 2013 Update 2 - everything needed for WP8.1 is there. Also if you wish to develop Windows Store apps (universal or something) you should install Windows 8.1 SDK [from here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/bg162891.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Look a bit bown in the list on your screenshot. On the same level the 2nd last option is Windows Phone. That should be it.

Comment: Thanks Fnupp, but that still targets 8.0. It should be under Windows Store -> Windows Phone App to target 8.1. I also don't have an option to change the target to 8.1 instead of 8 for phones either.